Mean of probability distribution
I have a probability distribution defined by the following density function:
$f(k,j,n,m)=\frac{(m n)! \mathcal{S}_k^{(j)}}{(m n)^k (m n-j)!}$ (With $\mathcal{S}_k^{(j)}$ being the Stirling number of the second kind.)
Here you can see a sample plot for $j=29,n=30,m=1$, with $k$ being the horizontal axis:

My goal is to calculate its mean to get an expected value for $k$, but when I apply the definition I get the following expression:
$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{k (m n)! \mathcal{S}_k^{(j)} (m n)^{-k}}{(m n-j)!}$
How can I solve this summation so that it can provide a resulting expression as a function of $j,n$ and $m$?

you could consider using numerics

@fgdu94 I need to get the complete expression, not approximations.

Stirling numbers of the second kind appear in occupancy problems like the coupon collectors problem and the birthday problem, which often have simple expressions for expectations by using linearity of expectation rather than sums like yours (presumably of a discrete distribution on the integers rather than a continuous density).  What does your distribution represent?

Incidentally, $m$ and $n$ only seem to appear as their product $mn$ in your expression.

As a further thought, the values in your chart do not sum to $1$ (some individual values look as if they are over $40$) and I am not sure $\sum\limits_k \frac{(m n)! \mathcal{S}_k^{(j)}}{(m n)^k (m n-j)!}=1$ either (my attempt seemed to get a sum of $30$ for your example).  What is this trying to represent?

Using Wolfram Alpha to check, it looks like it sum to $1$ indeed.
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+k+%3D+j+to+infty+%28mn%29%21S2%28k%2C+j%29%2F%28mn%29%5Ek%2F%28mn-j%29%21
But the expectation sum exceeded the computational time
